Correct use of ThrowIfCancellationRequested
I am trying to get my head around the operation of CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(). I believe it is working to a degree but I just want to see if this is the correct pattern for its usage.
I have a Windows form with 2 buttons - one to start the task and one to cancel it. And my code is:
public partial class CancelForm : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public CancelForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        
        await Task.Run(ThingDoingTask);

        if (_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Task Cancelled.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Task completed!");
        }
    }

    private void ThingDoingTask()
    {
        var task = DoSomethingThatTakesALongTime();

        try
        {
            task.Wait(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The task was cancelled");
        }
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingThatTakesALongTime()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something that takes a long time");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Count: {i}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished doing it");
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}

Now this works, in the sense that when I press btnCancel it catches the exception, and then the "Task Cancelled" messagebox pops up.
However it seems a very inelegant - first of all I have to do a Task.Run(ThingDoingTask) to create a new thread that itself calls what I really want to do with task.Wait() to pass it the cancellation token. This is because task.Wait() is blocking so if I just call from btnStart_Click() I can't press the 'Cancel' button. (and even though Task.Run() does accept the token, it doesn't throw the exception when I cancel.) Then I have to double-check the IsCancellationRequested after it completes because it doesn't know whether the exception was thrown.
Secondly the DoSomethingThatTakesALongTime() method continues even after it's thrown the exception. I could check IsCancellationRequested in here as well I suppose, but I thought the point of ThrowIfCancellationRequested() was to avoid peppering the code with lots of checks of the token? And the token isn't actually available in this method (it just happens to be a private property of this simple demonstration class - but this wouldn't be very useful in complex applications)
What is the correct way to code that simple application or use ThrowIfCancellationRequested ?

Maybe you should start by telling us what you are trying to do. What do you want to happen when the btnCancel is clicked? Is your intention to terminate/kill/abort the DoSomethingThatTakesALongTime operation in a non-cooperative manner?

@TheodorZoulias - yes, kind of, but it's more to get an understanding of how it's supposed to work.  - but yes, it's possible that DoSomethingThatTakesALongTime would make an API call or something else that might get stuck or take too long, and I'd like to be able to allow the user to cancel it.

There is no middle ground between cooperative and non-cooperative cancellation. There is little benefit in showing you how to perform the one kind of cancellation, if you are interested for the other. Is the actual core operation that you want to forcefully abort synchronous or asynchronous? If it's asynchronous see here.

There's no magic here. Either the long-running thing supports being cancelled (because it explicitly accepts and checks a CancellationToken), or it doesn't. If it doesn't, you can choose to just abandon waiting for it, but it will still continue to run in the background.

There's multiple levels of "I don't know why you're doing that" here. DoSomethingThatTakesALongTime is async, yet you're blocking synchronously on it in ThingDoingTask, then to avoid blocking the UI thread you're running that on the ThreadPool from btnStart_Click, and then awaiting that.
The thing about CancellationTokens is that they're cooperative: the thing which does the long-running work needs to periodically check the token to see whether it's been cancelled.
Using token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() is a useful way to do this. This throws an OperationCanceledException, which means that 1) your method exits and you don't need to worry about it, and 2) your caller knows that you were cancelled, because you threw an OperationCanceledException.
(Note that CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested is almost never actually used in practice.)
In your case, all you need is:
public partial class CancelForm : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public CancelForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        
        try
        {
            await DoSomethingThatTakesALongTimeAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token)
            MessageBox.Show("Task completed!");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Task Cancelled.");
        }
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingThatTakesALongTimeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something that takes a long time");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Count: {i}");

            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished doing it");
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}

Notice how I'm passing the CancellationToken into DoSomethingThatTakesALongTimeAsync (separation of concerns), and how I'm checking it on every loop?
(In fact, this is sub-optimal: if the token is cancelled, then the Task.Delay won't be cancelled, so we might take up to 2 seconds to cancel. You should really pass the token to Task.Delay, which will cause it to stop and throw an OperationCanceledException immediately. And if you do that, there's not much need to check the token again straight afterwards. I wrote my example the way I did as it more closely mirrors actual long-running work).

IsCancellationRequested is useful when you need to do something before throw. It's mentioned on msdn (comment in example).

@Sinatr Sure, but in practice I don't think it's ever used. Cleanup gets handled the normal way by try/finally (which covers other exception types as well)

@Sinatr the ratio of correct vs incorrect usage of the IsCancellationRequested from my experience here in StackOverflow is about 1:10. People routinely use incorrectly the IsCancellationRequested in places where they should use the ThrowIfCancellationRequested instead.

'There's multiple levels of "I don't know why you're doing that" here.' - that's why I've asked the question! Other sources indicated using Task.Wait and it threw the exception whereas Task.Run didn't - but it blocked the UI and can't be awaited.

"You should really pass the token to Task.Delay" - I've put Task.Delay here just for testing reasons but actually that could be replaced with things like calls to an API or other long-running processes that don't accept a CancellationToken. My goal I suppose is for the user to be able to cancel an operation, if, for example an API call gets stuck for a long time or something similar.

"Other sources indicated using Task.Wait" -- you should almost never use Task.Wait, especially from the UI thread of a UI application. "I've put Task.Delay here just for testing reasons" -- yep, as I addressed 2 sentences after that one. "My goal I suppose is for the user to be able to cancel an operation, if, for example an API call gets stuck for a long time or something similar" -- yep, and those operations must support cooperative cancellation, and accept a CancellationToken which you pass them
